# Why does the provided command as a parameter not run in a loop in my script?

Tags: shell-script, exec

I made a simple script that executed a command every minute:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

while true; do
    exec "$@"
    sleep 60
done
```

The idea is to make it as a [Docker entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) that will allow me to run the Laravel scheduler. But before building the image I thought to give it a test:

```
$ ./entrypoint/entrypoint_cron.sh echo "Hello"
Hello
```

But the command is executed only once. Why? And how I can make the command provided in the argument to run in a continuous loop till I terminate it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `exec` command replaces the current process with the new one. A successful execution means that there is nothing left to continue the script.

POSIX (the documentation for `sh`, also see `man sh`) writes it [like this](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exec),

> If `exec` is specified with command, it shall replace the shell with command without creating a new process. If arguments are specified, they shall be arguments to command.

Perhaps you meant this?

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
    "$@"
    sleep 60
done
```